# Python Project with several modules dependences at several levels for develop

Tags: python

I have a project, this project has several modules, let's pick this as an example:

Utility: all modules that use this module have shared functions

Read: This will read files with some configurations provided in the init function, can be called needed.

Process Data 1 (PD1): This will work with some data read with the "Read" module.

Process Data 2: This will work with some data read with the "Read" module and will use Process Data 2.

Manage: This will register any process data and handle them.

First, Utility will be used for all the modules, so, I can't just copy the module folder inside of any module that wants to use it. The dependency of PD1, PD2, and Manage causes that the module Manage needs to can load or access to the PD1, but PD2 needs PD1 too. There is the Read module too, with similar problems.

But, where is the problem?, Usually, if we add a new module, we put them in folders, especially if have a lot of files to don't mix up things, but this doesn't work fine here, excluding symbolic links, there is no way by only sorting the folders to have the right access to any section, well, there are some ways, but here is the point:

1. If we sort it all now, add a new module that uses the right modules, can break the actual sort.
2. I try the next thing, I put all the modules folders in a folder, and then add the ".." path, so now I can call any module I need for any existent or new module, but this has several problems... the import function start doing weird things, workaround, first import all external modules, then add the new ones..., but is a bit..., too much messy.

There is a bigger solution, I can handle all the modules in an independent way, install all of them in the system, so now all the modules are exposed to the others, and all works properly, and that is how should works, conceptually and in python terms is right. The major issue here is that installing all in this way is, developing time-consuming. I will test the "system" if I don't have installed everything... but install it every time for every single test.

Another thing to consider is that, if I install all the modules in the system, and I work with too many of them..., there can be a conflict with other modules names.., so, I need a way to can "encapsulate" all these modules with 1 module, and only can expose all of them, "inside" of this module.

Summary, I need a "Super module" that will be exposed to the system, and inside the super module, it needs to contain, Utility, Read, PD1, PD2, and Manage, where all of these modules needs to can call every one of them, without including any new "path" to python variables in any way.